# Sails.js one to many embedded associations with mongo

Tags: mongodb, sails.js

On the sails documentation [here](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/Associations/OnetoMany.html) it shows modeling one to many associations with what looks like high level referencing.
Lets say I want to use mongo to make a post that has a lot of comments on it. I will take the post as the document and in it I will embed all the comments in one attribute.
If I did it like the documentation, would the mongo adapter automatically, create a document with the comments embedded? or would it do something relational and reference the comments?

If it doesn't embed, how would I go about putting the embedded comments in my model?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mongo doesn't provide associations on its own. Sails uses [Waterline](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline) for ORM.

You need to create your Comment object yourself and just add its id to the appropriate attribute in the Post instance(which should be a `collection`), using `post.comments.add(comment.id)`.

Removal is similar, just call `post.comments.remove(comment.id)`

Note that at some point you might not like to have thousands of commentids being fetched every time you retrieve a Post (or worse, thousands of Comment documents if you populate and fetch). This, of course, is only a concern if you're expecting thousands of comments per post in the first place.

Oh, and don't forget to save your document to finalize the changes.